# Shared Memory issue in C

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory

I just re-post my previous question. I just compacted the code as much as it works and the functionality is the same as the main project.

shared memory. she_demo.c

```
#define DATA_LEN 10
char *key = "/shm1";

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
void initalize(void){
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
}

void *reader(void* arg) {
    char pack[10];
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    int shm_fd = shm_open(key, O_CREAT | O_RDONLY , S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (shm_fd == -1) {
        printf("Could not open shared memory \n");
        return (void*)-1;
    }

    void *shmp_rd = mmap(NULL, DATA_LEN, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
    if(shmp_rd == MAP_FAILED){
        printf("Mapping failed\n");
        return (void*)-1;
    }

    memcpy(pack, shmp_rd, DATA_LEN);

    if (munmap(shmp_rd, DATA_LEN) == -1) {
        printf("Unmapping failed\n");
        return (void*) NULL;
    }
    shm_unlink(key);
    close(shm_fd);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    return (void*)pack;
}

void *writer(void *arg) {
    char pack[10];
    strcpy(pack, (char*)arg);
    printf("%s\n", pack);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    int shm_fd = shm_open(key, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (shm_fd == -1) {
        printf("Could not create shared memory\n");
        return (void*)-1;
    }

    if (ftruncate(shm_fd, DATA_LEN) == -1) {
        printf("Error on ftruncate to allocate \n");
        return (void*)-1;
    }

    void *shmp_wr =  mmap(NULL, DATA_LEN, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
    if(shmp_wr == MAP_FAILED){
        printf("Mapping failed\n");
        return (void*)-1;
    }
    memcpy(shmp_wr, pack, strlen(pack));

    if (munmap(shmp_wr, DATA_LEN) == -1) {
        printf("Unmapping failed\n");
        return (void*)-1;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    close(shm_fd);
    return (void*)1;
}
```

server.c

```
#define DATA_LEN 70
#define SOCKET_NAME "socket"

extern void *writer(void*);
extern void initalize(void);

int main(){
  char *item[6] ={"Bruno", "Ben", "Zack", "Jack"};
  pthread_t tid;
  int connection_socket, data_socket, ret; //crete socket
    struct sockaddr_un name;
    unlink(SOCKET_NAME);
    connection_socket = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(connection_socket == -1){
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }
    memset(&name, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    name.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(name.sun_path, SOCKET_NAME, sizeof(name.sun_path) - 1);
    ret = bind(connection_socket, (const struct sockaddr *) &name, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    ret = listen(connection_socket, 20);
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }
    data_socket = accept(connection_socket, NULL, NULL);
    void* ret_vpr;
    int i = 0;
    char sync[5];
    strcpy(sync, "ADD");
    while(i < 4){
      printf("%d:\n", i);
      write(data_socket, sync, strlen(sync));

      pthread_create(&tid, NULL, writer, (void *)item[i]);
      pthread_join(tid, &ret_vpr);
      if((int)ret_vpr == 1){

      }
      i++;
    }
    close(data_socket);
      close(connection_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

client.c

```
#define DATA_LEN 70
#define SOCKET_NAME "socket"
extern void *reader(void*);

int main(void){
  pthread_t tid;
  char *item[4];
  void *ret_vpr;
    struct sockaddr_un addr;// create socket
    int data_socket = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (data_socket == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(addr.sun_path, SOCKET_NAME, sizeof(addr.sun_path) - 1);
    if (connect(data_socket, (const struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "The server is down.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("connected\n"); // create socket
    int rc = 1;
    char ch[6];
    while(rc){
      rc = read(data_socket, ch, sizeof(ch));
      if(rc < 0){
          perror("read");
          break;
      }
      ch[rc] = '\0';
      printf("%s\n", ch);
      if(!strcmp(ch, "ADD")){
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, reader, NULL);
            pthread_join(tid, &ret_vpr);
        printf("%s\n", (char *) ret_vpr);
      }
    }
    close(data_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

Unpredictable seg-fault happens when I run the project. First, the server should be run and then client. I think the problem is in client side, when the program wants to execute **printf("%s\n", (char *) ret_vpr);**.

Comment: Why are you using threads if you serialize them with a _join_ immediately after _create_?  In any case, let me ask you to please cut this down dramatically to a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Perhaps start a "server" process that writes its pid to the shared memory, then a manually invoked "client" process that reads it while the server is still running.  Then maybe add socket IPC to coordinate it.  Then maybe add threads if you think that adds something.  I suspect you'll find your problem if you do this.

Comment: @pilcrow
- I'm using threads because I have to benchmark the throughput of entire program by increasing the number of threads. 
- The architecture of this system is like this: server starts and the admin may add some data to its local table. After a while, another process connects to the server to sync its table with that of the server. the table is shared via shared memory and any operation in the server on its corresponding table is informed to other processes via their pids through socket. simultaneously, the server puts new added data or data to be deleted to the shared memory.

Comment: On the other side, the client receive operation code via socket and realizes that there is a data in the shared memory which should be  added or deleted according to the operation.

Comment: Please cut it down to an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating just one problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do not try at all to run a program from your code but your problem  can be the next two lines are in the wrong order

```
pthread_cond_wait(&cnd, &mutex);
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
```

it must be

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
pthread_cond_wait(&cnd, &mutex);
```

so the reader is not well synchronized

you have to get the mutex before to call pthread_cond_wait

---

[edit] additional remarks :

In the writter you do :

```
char shm_data[70];
sprintf(shm_data, "%s -> %s", pack->data, pack->hash);
memcpy(shmp_wr, shm_data, strlen(shm_data));
```

first why 70 rather than DATA_LEN (+1), same problem in the reader with sizes 32

second are you sure you do not write out of shm_data and/or shmp_wr ?

finaly you do not copy the null character ending the string, in the reader you do *sscanf(shm_data, "%s -> %s", data, hash)* and that one need the final null character

Also it is very strange to do

```
    int i = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, reader, NULL);
```

and immediately after

```
    i = pthread_join(tid, &ret_vpr);
```

just do the job in the current thread

---

[edit from your last version]

The function *reader* returns the address of the **local** variable *pack*, out of the function that address cannot be unreferenced without an undefined behavior. But you use it in

> ```
> printf("%s\n", (char *) ret_vpr);
> ```

Allocate *pack* in the heap rather than to place it in the stack in *reader*. Of course in the error cases return for instance NULL and check *ret_vpr* is not NULL before to call *printf* in *main*

After these changes the execution of the server and client are :

```
$ ./server 
0:
Bruno
1:
Ben
2:
Zack
3:
Jack

$ ./client 
connected
ADD
Jack
ADD
Bruno
ADD
Ben
ADD
Zack
```

Comment: didn't work. in first program, only the first node of the linked list is written in the shared memory and second program can read it. Other nodes which should be written in the shared memory, are not written. Writer function throws "Could not create shared memory".

Comment: @BenEslami Anyway the lines are in the wrong order and you have to fix that. Why you didn't not speak about that error before, did you hope we can guess what you don't say ? Modify your program to write the value of _errno_ when you have that error to know the reason, you can also use _strerror_ etc

Comment: I put perror("error") in write function below the line "printf("Could not create shared memory\n");" . The result is "Invalid Argument"

Comment: @BenEslami I asked you to give _errno_ value (and may be _perror_ ), there are several possibilities to have "invalid argument". What is/are the value(s) of _key_ ?

Comment: Value of errno: 22

Comment: @BenEslami can you understand it is difficult to help you while each time you do not answer to all the questions ? I also asked you about _key_, this is enforced if 22 is also "EINVAL The name argument to shm_open() was invalid." for you

Comment: key value is a global value:
char *key = "/shm";

Comment: ok, the problem is there several other possibilities, including invalid memory accesses, but a lot of definitions/initializations are hidden, we need a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Out of that why do you use pthread_create to do just after pthread_join, just do the work in the current thread

Comment: This project is to benchmarking throughput by increasing the number of threads.
I feel this problem is because I'm running it on Mac OSX.

Comment: @BenEslami I edited my answer, but again we need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) else it is impossible to help you more and your question will be closed for that reason probably

Comment: I'm examining your hints you just added in your answer.
Also, I just added more information about the problem in my question.

Comment: @BenEslami are the client and server two different processes ? if yes I do not understand the use of the condition

Comment: Yes they are two different processes. Use of the condition is because I didn't know anything else to do. :))

Comment: @BenEslami reduce your code the more is possible to reproduce the problem then publish all of it, I already ask you several times for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) , until you do I will not use more time for you even I am confined because of the covid-19 ...

Comment: Hi @bruno, I just did what you said before.

Comment: @BenEslami yes, that allowed me to find, see the end of my edited answer